# Order posts by condition

Tags: query-posts, order

I need to get 15 posts. If there are any with a tag `featured`, I want them to be first. If there are none, I want the rest to be random posts.

My idea was to sort posts  based on a condition `tag=featured` DESC and randomly. Can I do that using `query_posts()`?

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=15&orderby=((tag=featured),rand)&order=desc';
```

Thank you.

Comment: Regardless of the answer to this question, you should ***never*** use `query_posts`, and you should pass in your query arguments using an array if you want anything other than the most basic/trivial queries. Consider the `pre_get_posts` filter or `WP_Query` instead

Comment: I'm not currently in the position to code, but you'll need to get 15 random posts regardless. The kind of sorting you are after is not available in Wordpress. You will need to sort the returned array of `$posts` with `usort`. Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/161553/31545). This should get you there

Answer (score 1):

As Tom said, you should never use `query_posts` and should almost always pass any arguments as an array.

I think this will achieve what you want:

```php
<?php

    // Arguments
    $args = array('
        'nopaging'          => true,
        'terms'             => 'featured',
        'posts_per_page'    => 15,
        'orderby'           => 'rand',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
    ');

    // The query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            /*
                Output here, e.g.
                echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
                echo '<div>' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
            */

        }
    }

?>
```