# show category name before first posts in each category

Tags: categories, loop

I want sort posts in the loop by category and before first post in each category display category name.

For example:

```
Category 1
   Post
   Post
   Post
Category 2
   Post
   Post
   Post
   Post
Category 3
   Post
```

etc.

Is it possible to do this using one loop?

p.s. sorry for my terrible english.

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161915/31545) can be a good start to sort by category

Comment: Another [approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/184993/31545), anyone of the three given answers :-)

Comment: [Another approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with two queries, the first to get your taxonomies like this :

```
$categories = get_categories();
```

More infos about the params [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).
And then browse your category collections and get the first n posts of it like this :

```
foreach($categories as $cat)
{
    //get the $n posts from this category
    $post_query = new WP_Query(
        array('post_type' => 'post',
          'posts_per_page' => $n ,
          'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => $cat->taxonomy,
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => $cat->term_id,
               )
         )
       )
    );
    echo '<h2>'.$cat->name.'</h2>';
    while($post_query->have_posts()){
       $post_query->the_post();
       echo get_the_title();
    }wp_reset_query();
}
```

Hope it will help =)

Comment: Just note, your approach works, but is really expensive and you can run into queries timing out with large amount of posts and categories. :-)

Comment: Totally agree, I'm reading the link you posted as a comment to learn the "clean approach", but in most of cases it's the fastest way to get things done on a small website in my opinion.